# Как скачать только папки и файлы без репозитория?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-clone

Мне надо **просто слить репозиторий, без инициализции гита**, без истории изменений, без веток. Просто папки и файлы. Как это сделать?

Проблема состоит в следующем: если делать `git clone`, то мы выкачиваем ее и всю историю и по сути инициализируем гит. Если сделать `git init`, `git add remote ...`, `git pull` - тоже инициализируем гит в директории. Других способов я не знаю.

Comment: самим git никак я думаю, можно слить так чтобы директория .git была вне рабочей. можно сначала слить, а потом скопировать без .git. можно на git-shell (на серверной стороне) нарисовать что-нить типа хука - сделать архив или как-то по другому выдать содержимое.

Comment: @zb': оказывается, можно )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Вариант А**: мелкое (неглубокое, shallow) клонирование, а затем убрать все `.git*`. Это клонирует репо без истории:

```
git clone --depth=1 git@github.com:xxx/yyy.git
```

**Вариант Б**: `git archive`. Это сольёт файлы репо в ZIP'е:

```
git archive --format zip --remote=git@github.com:xxx/yyy.git HEAD
```

Answer (score 6):

Есть несколько вариантов решения этой задачи:

## Через неполное клонирование

Используйте [параметр `--depth` команды `git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

```
git clone --depth=1 <remote-url>
```

При этом создается «неполный» (shallow) репозиторий. Из документации:

> Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions.
>
> Создать неполный клон, в котором история будет ограничена указанным количеством последних коммитов.

В Git до версии 2.0 неполный клон имел существенные ограничения на последующие pull/push/fetch, но начиная с 2.0 эти ограничения были устранены. Теперь вы можете «добрать» остальные коммиты или их часть следующим образом:

```
# последние 10 коммитов
git fetch --depth=10

# все
git fetch --unshallow
```

## Через `git archive`

Можно использовать [команду `git archive` с параметром `--remote`](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-archive). При этом удаленный сервер создает архив с содержимым последнего коммита и передает его вам. Локальный репозиторий при этом не создается.

```
# сохранить в архив
git archive --format=tar --remote=<remote-url> HEAD > archive.tar

# сразу распаковать в текущий путь
git archive --format=tar --remote=<remote-url> HEAD | tar -xf -
```

Поддерживаемые форматы: tar, zip.

Не каждый сервер Git поддерживает этот функционал, и многие накладывают ограничения на передаваемый адрес. Если вы неуспешно использовали относительный адрес (вроде `master^^~2^~3`), попробуйте точный sha-1 коммита.

Comment: Писал как самостоятельный вопрос и ответ, потом нашёл этот вопрос. Оставил, т.к. ответ более подробный.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте команду `svn export` с URL репозитория GitHub, указав путь к папке, которую вы хотите скопировать.

1. `$ apt install subversion`
2. `$ svn export https://github.com/ИмяПользователя/НазваниеРепозитория/путь/к/папке`

Важно: на примере url для скачивания папки "ansible":

```
https://github.com/netology-group/virt-homeworks/tree/virt-11/05-virt-04-docker-compose/src/ansible
```

блок:

```
/tree/virt-11/
```

заменить на:

```
/trunk/
```

Вуаля! **"ansible"** со всем содержимым "залетает" в вашу текущую директорию:

```
$ svn export https://github.com/netology-group/virt-homeworks/trunk/05-virt-04-docker-compose/src/ansible
```

Comment: В чем смысл установки еще одной системы контроля версий?