# Случайно форкнул проект в GitHub, как теперь его удалить?

Tags: git, github

Случайно форкнул проект в GitHub. Проект x64dbg. Удалил у себя все файлы,
но каталог master x64dbg остался.

Как от него избавиться? И желательно от истории тоже.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Форк — это самостоятельный репозиторий на GitHub, он создается для того, чтобы вы могли продолжить работу над проектом, сохранили всю историю изменений до форка и могли делать пулл-реквесты.

Если вам нужно только получить последнюю версию проекта, то форк для этого не нужен. Можно клонировать «родительский» репозиторий, причём достаточно будет [неполного (неглубокого) клонирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/324693/181472).

**Чтобы полностью удалить любой проект на GitHub (не обязательно форк):**

1. Перейдите на страницу проекта (репозитория).
2. В правой части экрана нажмите на вкладку <kbd>Settings</kbd> в виде шестерёнки.

> [image]

3. В разделе Danger zone нажмите <kbd>Delete this repository</kbd>

> [image]

4. В текстовое поле введите полное название вашего репозитория

> [image]

5. Нажмите кнопку под текстовым полем для подтверждения.

Comment: Nick Volynkin, привет.  У меня похожая ситуация, но не совсем такая же.  Я не форкал репу, но она у меня в списке... Не подписывался на нее. Как удалить репу я знаю. Но не смотря, что она у меня в списке, нет раздела "setting", чтобы ее удалить... Как мне от нее отписаться и как удалить?

Comment: @Air а в каком она списке? Можете ссылку кинуть?

Comment: Nick Volynkin, благодарю, уже разобрался...

Comment: @Air подскажите, как вы решили данный вопрос. У меня точно такая же проблема - делал форк репозитория, теперь хочу удалить, но кнопка settings отсутсвует

Comment: @Famous, в моем случае мне надо было отписать, я отписался...

Comment: @Air вопрос решен - владелец репозитория заприватил его и у меня форкнутый репозиторий исчез.

Answer (score 6):

Форк происходит на сервере, руководство по удалению репозитария вот: https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository/

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Я имел ввиду что случайно нажал на кнопку Форк на странице проекта. А как откатить это действие не знал. Огромное спасибо!